# How to set sagemaker retry policy for pipeline steps for AlgorithmError

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

On a sagemaker project, i have a pipeline containing several steps. In particular, the **batch transform step** has some internal problems which occur infrequently and i am therefore unable to replicate the error.

This step goes into "**AlgorithmError**" after 16 long hours (i have not set any timeout), even though the problem occurs immediately.

**The current solution** is that after the step has failed, i can do a manual retry of the pipeline (e.g. the "retry" button on SageMaker Studio) and restart this step with a good chance that it will not fail again. For the moment it always works, but i would like to automate this retry. Clearly, this is a way around the problem while waiting for the final solution.

I have seen that there is a "[Retry Policy for Pipeline Steps](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-sagemaker-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/pipelines-retry-policy.md#retry-policy-for-pipeline-steps)" and batch transform jobs also apply, but I have not quite understood which of the "[**Supported exception types**](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-sagemaker-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/pipelines-retry-policy.md#supported-exception-types-for-the-retry-policy)" is suitable and how to configure it for "AlgorithmError".

---

To put it in context, this is my simple pipeline step code (so configurational parts of retry, retries etc. are all by default):

```py
from sagemaker.transformer import Transformer
from sagemaker.workflow.steps import TransformStep
from sagemaker.inputs import TransformInput

transformer = Transformer(
    model_name=my_model.properties.ModelName,
    instance_count=test_processor_instance_count,
    instance_type=test_processor_instance_type,
    output_path=my_output_test_path,
)
        
step_transform = TransformStep(
    name="TestInference",
    description="Test Inference",
    transformer=transformer,
    inputs= TransformInput(
        data=my_data_s3_uri,
        content_type = 'application/octet-stream',
        data_type = 'S3Prefix'
    )  
)
```

Is it possible to avoid waiting 16 hours before it fails? The whole step takes about 1 hour normally.

How do I set the automatic retry in case of an AlgorithmError?

Comment: In general `AlgorithmError` is a non retryable error. It depicts something went wrong with the training script.

Comment: The problem is not in the training but in the inference script. And as I said, the problem on the same dataset and same parameters only appears a few times so I cannot reproduce it. The problem is that sometimes it does not install some libraries (there is some package installation code inside the python code).